# Gradle build issues in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Good day beautiful people. I am new to flutter. For the past 4 days, i have been trying build my first flutter project and here is what i see in my android studio.

***Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > Connect to 192.168.43.253:80 [/192.168.43.253] failed: Connection refused: connect
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > Connect to 192.168.43.253:80 [/192.168.43.253] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Connect to 192.168.43.253:80 [/192.168.43.253] failed: Connection refused: connect
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Connect to 192.168.43.253:80 [/192.168.43.253] failed: Connection refused: connect

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 52s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1***

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: It does appear like your network connection!

Comment: Post your flutter doctor.  Also, try flutter upgrade and flutter clean.

Comment: Hello Whales_Corps, I originally felt it was from my network connection, I finally used a VPN, yet the issue persisted

Comment: Scott Godfrey, I upgraded to flutter 1.20, ran flutter doctor, all came out clean!!! Yet the issue still persisted.